# Z3 Optimization, strict inqualities

Tags: python, z3, z3py, optimathsat

I'm having a problem which was referred to before where I do not quite get the solution (combining substitute with simplify). In my encoding, I have strict inequalities and I would need to set the epsilon either to 0 or to a very small value. For instance, I have the following simplified Python code:

```
from z3 import *

p = Real('p')
q = Real('q')
s = Optimize()

s.add(p > 0, p < 1)
s.add(q > 0, q < 1)
h = s.maximize(p)

print s.check()
print s.upper(h)
print s.model()
```

How can I get p to be assigned the maximal value 1? (Right now it is assigned 1/2.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use `code` formatting.

Comment: So, the real problem seems to be that the optimal value for a variable is not the one returned by the model. Is this an desired result? In my encodings I would need the exact values for all variables that induce the optimal value for the target function.

Comment: Is it an option to use non-strict inequalities?  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061619/z3-maximization-api-possible-bug).

Answer (score 2):

**Premise**:

1. I assume that you simply want a model in which `p` *approaches 1* with *a fixed precision*.
2. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061619/z3-maximization-api-possible-bug) N.B. states **(emphasis is mine)**

> epsilon refers to a non-standard number (infinitesimal). You can set it arbitrarily small. Again the **model uses only standard numbers**, so it picks **some number**, in this case 9.

Given that..

- I could not find any option to set `epsilon` neither in the Python API nor among *smt2* options
- By changing the size of the interval of `x`, the value of `x` in the returned model is at a different distance from the optimal value (e.g. interval `0, 10` gives `x=9`, whereas `0, 1` gives`x=0.5`)

..my take of the previous quote is that *z3* picks some *random* satisfiable value, and that's it.

---

**Therefore**:

I would do it in the following way:

```
from z3 import *

epsilon = 0.0000001

p = Real('p')
q = Real('q')
s = Optimize()

s.add(p > 0, p < 1)
s.add(q > 0, q < 1)

s.push()
h = s.maximize(p)

print s.check() # Here I assume SAT

opt_value = h.value()

if epsilon in opt_value: # TODO: refine
    s.pop()
    opt_term = instantiate(opt_value, epsilon) # TODO: encode this function

    s.add(p > opt_value)

    s.check()

    print s.model()
else:
    print s.model()
    s.pop()
```

Where `instantiate(str, eps)` is a *custom-made* function that parses strings in the shape of `ToReal(1) + ToReal(-1)*epsilon` and returns the result of the *obvious* interpretation of such string.

### ----

I'd like to mention that an alternative approach is to encode the problem as an *smt2* formula and give it as input to [OptiMathSAT](http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/):

```
(set-option:produce-models true)

(declare-fun p () Real)
(declare-fun q () Real)

(assert (and (< 0 p) (< p 1)))
(assert (and (< 0 q) (< q 1)))

(maximize p)

(check-sat)
(set-model 0)
(get-model)
```

*OptiMathSAT* has a *command-line* option `-optimization.theory.la.epsilon=N` to control the value of `epsilon` within the returned *model* of the formula. By default `N=6` and `epsilon` is `10^-6`. Here is the output:

```
### MAXIMIZATION STATS ###
# objective:      p (index: 0)
# interval:     [ -INF , +INF ]
#
# Search terminated!
# Exact strict optimum found!
# Optimum: <1
# Search steps: 1 (sat: 1)
#  - binary: 0 (sat: 0)
#  - linear: 1 (sat: 1)
# Restarts: 1 [session: 1]
# Decisions: 3 (0 random) [session: 3 (0 random)]
# Propagations: 6 (0 theory) [session: 13 (0 theory)]
# Watched clauses visited: 1 (0 binary) [session: 2 (1 binary)]
# Conflicts: 3 (3 theory) [session: 3 (3 theory)]
# Error:
#  - absolute: 0
#  - relative: 0
# Total time: 0.000 s
#  - first solution: 0.000 s
#  - optimization: 0.000 s
#  - certification: 0.000 s
# Memory used: 8.977 MB
sat
( (p (/ 1999999 2000000))
  (q (/ 1 2000000)) )
```

Comment: Substituting `epsilon` with `0.0000001` and adding the constraint forcing `p` to be assigned larger than `opt_value` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it truly qualifies as a full answer though, at best is a temporary tweak. If I could post it as a comment I would have done it. Perhaps *z3* devs can give a proper answer.